# Debug code on one machine, run JBoss on another

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jboss, wildfly

Is it possible to setup JBoss server on one machine (PC) and then connect to it from another machine (laptop) ? I want to be able to run/deploy my application on the server on the PC and through Intellij on the laptop debug my code using that JBoss instance on the PC. I'm running a domain version of JBoss. Right now I have both the server and client running on the same machine. I'm not sure how to get around doing it, thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to remote debug your application.

If you look at the first lines in the startup script standalone.[sh|bat], you'll see that debug agent can be enabled with the --debug command switch.

Switching this debug option will enable the [JPDA](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/architecture.html) and will listen on port 8787 by default.

This can also be achieved using JAVA_OPTS (look at the end of standalone.conf[.bat])

Once you started WildFly, you'll need to add a remote debug configuration in IntelliJ using the IP and port of your server. Here is the [official documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/run-debug-configuration-remote.html).

For remote deployment, you should have a look at the [jboss-cli](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/CommandLineInterface).

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse you can connect as follows, I'm sure Intellij must have something similar as well:
Run-> Debug Configuration->Remote Java Application. Here you can define the Host and Port of the application server, irrespective of it's location, be it local or any remote location.